# Error while using SPARK-SUBMIT on Ubuntu VM

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark, spark-streaming

While trying to run this command from the book: Spark: the definitive guide. I ran into a problem. As far as I am concearned to do streaming in Spark I'll need to use "spark-submit" and not running Jupyter Notebook cells, hence I want to know how to use it properly.

[image]

Comment: Is your job completed or failing with some error? If failing, please post the error

Comment: Nope I just ran the cide pi.py that comes with Spark and that warn happens.